# Create a trigger to insert a row in order table on payment status is complete

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to create a trigger so as payment process regarding any deal is completed and admin set status to completed a new entry inserted in to order table with user detail like name and address and deal detail.

```
begin

 declare receipent_name varchar(225);
 declare receipent_number varchar(225);
 declare receipent_address varchar(225);

    IF (new.dj_status == 'completed')
    THEN

        select `user_name` into receipent_name,
               `user_contact_number` into receipent_number 
               `user_address_google` into receipent_address
               from users JOIN user_addresses ON user_id = user_address_user_id WHERE user_id = old.dj_user_id;

        INSERT INTO `order`(`or_dj_id`, `or_track_number`, `or_recipient_name`, `or_recipient_number`, `or_address`) 
            VALUES (old.dj_id,'',receipent_name,receipent_number,receipent_address);

    END IF;    

end
```

Comment: What is the question???

Comment: Question is what i am doing wrong ? Above trigger is showing error

Comment: I have called it on deal_join table update

Comment: So? You have what looks like the body of a create trigger statement so show the full statement. Then tell us if the trigger was created, then tell us what happens and what does not happen. Also, what am I doing wroing is meaningless without then error message itself..

Comment: ok ,

Can you give me an example to get data from a table and insert it in to another table by using trigger.


I want to create a trigger so as payment process regarding any deal is completed and admin set status to completed a new entry inserted in to order table with user detail like name and address and deal detail.

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx mysql triggers tutorial.